# ASSIGN fails with variable from debugger path

Tags: abap, assign

I am trying to assign the value of this stucture path to a fieldsymbol, but this path does not work because it has a table in it's path.

But with in the debugger this value of this path is shown correctly.

Is there a way to dynamically assign a component of a table line to a fieldsymbol, by passing one path?
If not then I will just read the table line and then use the path to get the wanted value.

```
ls_struct (Struct)
    - SUPPLYCHAINTRADETRANSACTION (Struct)
        - INCL_SUPP_CHAIN_ITEM (Table)
            - ASSOCIATEDDOCUMENTLINEDOCUMENT (Element)   


i_component_path = |IG_DDIC-SUPPLYCHAINTRADETRANSACTION-INCL_SUPP_CHAIN_ITEM[1]-ASSOCIATEDDOCUMENTLINEDOCUMENT|.
ASSIGN (i_component_path) TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lg_value>).
IF <lg_value> IS NOT ASSIGNED.
    return.
ENDIF.

<lg_value> won't be assigned
```

Comment: The debugger has its own syntax and own logic, it doesn't apply the `ASSIGN` algorithm at all. With ABAP source code, you have to use `ASSIGN` twice, the first one to reach the internal table, then you select the first line, and the second one to reach the component of the line.

Comment: @SandraRossi Is there no way I can use the functionality of the debugger? Or do you know a function/class that is able to assign the value with a "structure path" like this?

Thank you for your fast answer

Comment: The debugger works completely differently, the debugger code works only in debug mode, you can't call the code from the debugger (i.e. if you call it, the kernel code used by the debugger will fail). No, there's no "abappath". There are the XSL transformation objects (xpath), but it's slow for what you ask.

Comment: have you tried to use not ASSIGN but string templates like this: `DATA(value) = |{ IG_DDIC-SUPPLYCHAINTRADETRANSACTION-INCL_SUPP_CHAIN_ITEM[ 1 ]-ASSOCIATEDDOCUMENTLINEDOCUMENT }|`? note the space is needed for the table expression after square brackets

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that value will always be a string?

Comment: In case Suncatcher's solution suits somebody (i.e. you don't actually need to assign component specified in a path), you can just assign directly: `assign IG_DDIC-SUPPLYCHAINTRADETRANSACTION-INCL_SUPP_CHAIN_ITEM[ 1 ]-ASSOCIATEDDOCUMENTLINEDOCUMENT to <FS>`.

Comment: `Wouldn't that mean that value will always be a string?` no. read about [string templates](https://software-heroes.com/en/blog/abap-string-templates-part-1) which are available since 7.31. Though I don't know if they will work particularly in your case, 'cause debugger structure may be nested manyfold

Comment: @Zero on what SAP version did you test this? I tried to do exactly that, but the "component path" was in a variable. It didn't work for me.

Comment: @stego What I proposed was an alternative to suncatcher's solution. He retrieves a value from using a hardcoded path, while I was pointing out you can assign hardcoded path directly using same path. You cannot do this with dynamic assignment. At least not in a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution by [Sandra Rossi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9150270/sandra-rossi)

The debugger has its own syntax and own logic, it doesn't apply the `ASSIGN` algorithm at all. With ABAP source code, you have to use `ASSIGN` twice, the first one to reach the internal table, then you select the first line, and the second one to reach the component of the line.

The debugger works completely differently, the debugger code works only in debug mode, you can't call the code from the debugger (i.e. if you call it, the kernel code used by the debugger will fail). No, there's no "abappath". There are the XSL transformation objects (xpath), but it's slow for what you ask.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a rather unexpected limitation of the `ASSIGN` statement. Probably worth a ticket to SAP's ABAP language group to clarify whether it's even a bug.

While this works:

```
ASSIGN data-some_table[ 1 ]-some_field TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_source>).
```

the same expressed as a string doesn't:

```
ASSIGN (`data-some_table[ 1 ]-some_field`) TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lv_source>).
```

[Alternative 1 for `(name)` of the ABAP keyword documentation for the `ASSIGN` statement](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abapassign_mem_area_dynamic_dobj.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_1@1@) says that "[t]he name in `name` is structured in the same way as if specified directly".

However, this declaration is immediately followed by "the content of name must be the name of a data object which may contain offsets and lengths, structure component selectors, and component selectors for assigning structured data objects and attributes in classes or objects", a list that *does not* include the [table expressions](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-us/abentable_expressions.htm) we would need here.

Comment: So did you file a ticket to SAP? I considered you a SAP employee yourself

Comment: To be honest, no, forgot about it, sorry. :-( But I'll do that now right away.