# Dynamic ASSIGN of table row expression

Tags: dynamic, abap

In my ABAP report I have some structure:

```
data: 
  begin of struct1,
    field1 type char10,
  end of struct1.
```

I can access to it's field field1 directly:

```
data(val) = struct1-field1
```

or dynamically with assign:

```
assign ('struct1-field1') to field-symbol(<val>).
```

Also I have some internal table:

```
data: table1 like standard table of struct1 with default key.
append initial line to table1.
```

I can access to column field1 of first row directly:

```
data(val) = table1[ 1 ]-field1.
```

But I can not get access to field1 with dynamic assign:

```
assign ('table1[ 1 ]-field1') to field-symbol(<val>).
```

After assignment sy-subrc equals "4".

Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASSIGN fails with variable from debugger path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187170/assign-fails-with-variable-from-debugger-path)

Comment: No, that topic is about debugger and its path syntax to variables components

Comment: Revisit that post - look at Florians answer. That should clarify this a little bit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187170/assign-fails-with-variable-from-debugger-path

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `ASSIGN (syntax1) ...` is not the same as the syntax of the Right-Hand Side (RHS) of assignments `... = syntax2`.

The syntax for ASSIGN is explained in the documentation of [`ASSIGN (variable_containing_name) ...` or `ASSIGN ('name') ...`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapassign_mem_area_dynamic_dobj.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_1@1@) (chapter 1. (name) of page ASSIGN - dynamic_dobj).

Here is an abstract of what is accepted:

- "name can contain a chain of names consisting of component selectors [(`-`)]"
- "the first name [can be] followed by an object component selector (`->`)"
- "the first name [can be] followed by a class component selector (`=>`)"

No mention of table expressions, so they are forbidden. Same for meshes...

Concerning the RHS of assignments, as described in the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenvalue_assignments.htm), it can be :

- Data Objects

  - They can be attributes or components using selectors `-`, `->`, `=>`, which can be chained multiple times (see [Names for Individual Operands](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenoperands_names.htm)
- Return values or results of functional methods, return values or results of built-in functions and constructor expressions, or return values or results of table expressions
- Results of calculation expressions

Answer (score 2):

Sandra is absolutely right, if table expressions are not specified in help, then they are not allowed.

You can use ASSIGN COMPONENT statement for your dynamicity:

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <tab> TYPE INDEX TABLE.

ASSIGN ('table1') TO <tab>.
ASSIGN COMPONENT 'field1' OF STRUCTURE <tab>[ 1 ] TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<val>).
```

However, such dynamics is only possible with index tables (standard + sorted) due to the nature of [this version of row specification](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abentable_exp_itab_line.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_1@1@). If you try to pass hashed table into the field symbol, it will dump.

Comment: Yeah, I kept in mind this two-liner. It is good for simple cases like "index_table1[ 1 ]-field1". But in case like "index_table1[ 1 ]-field1-index_table2[ 3 ]-field2" it requires additional coding.

Comment: Yep, there is no other way.